# Como subir foto tomada desde el teléfono a mi web mediante php

Tags: php, mysqli, web, php7, hosting

En si, el código funciona sin ningún problema si subo la imagen desde el ordenador, se suben los datos y la imagen, pero cuando abro mi web en el teléfono y hago el mismo procedimiento (con excepción que en vez de seleccionar el archivo tomo una foto) no envía o guarda la foto en la base de datos...

```
    if(isset($enviar)){
$nombre_donador = clear($nombre_donador);
$apellido_donador = clear($apellido_donador);
$numero_donador = clear($numero_donador);
$monto_donador = clear($monto_donador);

$imagen_comprobante = "";

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen_comprobante']['tmp_name'])){
    $imagen_comprobante = $nombre_donador.rand(0,1000).".png";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen_comprobante']['tmp_name'], "imagen_comprobante/".$imagen_comprobante);
}

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO registro_donaciones (nombre_donador,apellido_donador,numero_donador,monto_donador,imagen_comprobante) 
VALUES ('$nombre_donador','$apellido_donador','$numero_donador','$monto_donador','$imagen_comprobante')");
alert("Comprobante enviado!",1,"./");
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, los dos primeros datos, los subí sin ningún problema desde la web en la computadora, pero desde el teléfono no manda la foto, no se si debería de agregarle algún comando en especifico para los casos del teléfono o no se que podría hacer para enviar la imagen desde la web en teléfono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aquellos quienes tienen esta duda tambien, ya lo solucione... Solo deben de agregar la carpeta de en donde se guardan las fotos tomodas de la camara del telefono. En este caso le agrege despues del if:

```
    else 
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen_comprobante'] 
   ['tmp_name'])){
    $imagen_comprobante = 
     $nombre_donador.rand(0,1000).".png";
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen_comprobante']['tmp_name'],"/storage/emulated/DCIM/Camera/".$imagen_comprobante);
}
```

Y eso hace que vaya a la ruta de la camara, agarre la foto por así decirlo y la suba a la bd. Espero esto le pueda servir a alguien! Pd. (Lo probé con un samsung y iphone y funciono).